# some messages not received using nodeJS, mqtt and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mqtt

I am using NodeJS, mqtt and socket.io for my project.

I need to receive only 2 messages published via mqtt having for each a different topic created. However, sometimes one has to be sent twice to actually show it on the website.
It kinda gets lost as mqtt defenitely publishes it but my console doesn´t show the message.
I am using following code to handle incoming messages:

```
client.on('message', function(topic, message){
  sys.puts(topic+'='+message);
  io.sockets.emit('mqtt',{'topic':String(topic),
    'payload':String(message)});
});
```

I really cannot find the mistake. Everything seems fine to me. It´s pretty strange that sending it once works once in a while.

Did anybody have a similar problem?

Comment: There isn't enough information here for anybody to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the realconnectTime was too little.
Leaving the property 'realconnectTime' out worked perfectly fine for me